# Optimized counter for frequency of a character in a string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, time-complexity

I was solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_l=interview&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=false&page=44&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D=warmup&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) question which requires to count the number of 'a's in a string after doing a manipulation on it done upto line 6.

And the solution i came up with is this :

```
s='abcac'
n=52
x=n//len(s)
y=n%len(s)
k=s[:y]
s=(s*x)+k
from collections import Counter
print(s.count('a'))
```

-- pretty straightforward and simple . But it gives error when n is a large number eg 1000000000000.

How can i optimize my solution ? 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to build the extended string.  First, count the number of full repetitions of your string  that will fit in `n` characters: `n//len(s)`.  Then multiply this count by the number of "a" in the string.  Once you have that, you only need to figure out how much more of your string is needed to cover the remainder of the `n` characters: `n%len(s)`, and count  the number of "a" in that substring:

So, the result will simply be:

```
 n//len(s)*s.count("a") + s[:n%len(s)].count("a")
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention that "it gives error when n is a large number eg 1000000000000." Let's see what we're doing with n...

Variable `n` is the number of characters from the start that we care about. Also, based on `x = n // len(s)`, `x` is the number of *full* repetitions of string `s` we will encounter, and `y` is a substring that takes care of any "leftover"/"overflowing" letters.

Now a big red flag for me is the like `s = (s * x) + k`. Syntactically, this is fine — python supports string by integer multiplication. But let's see what happens in my interpreter when I run your code and make `n` very very big...

```
>>> string * 10000000000000000
python(<pid>,<memory-address>) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=10000000000004096) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>>
```

When we make an extended string like that, it takes memory to store that — and if each character of a string is 1 byte (let's assume just ASCII characters for simplicity), that line requires 10^12 or about one terabyte of information! That's infeasible.

I think the challenge here is to come up with a solution that doesn't require you to actually make the string — there are mathematical ways you can calculate the number of 'a's in the infinite string given that you know its substructure.

For reference, here is my solution:

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    num_a_in_substring = s.count('a')
    n_repetitions = n // len(s)
    overflow = s[:n%len(s)]
    return (num_a_in_substring * n_repetitions) + overflow.count('a')
```

Notice how instead of creating a giant in-memory version of our monstrous 10^12-character string, I calculate the number of a's in the smaller string and build off of that result. That way, I'm just juggling around a number instead of a giant string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
s='a'
n=100000
a=s.count('a')
x=n//len(s)
y=n%len(s)
k=s[:y]
b=k.count('a')
#s=(s*x)+k
print((a*x)+b)
```

I changed the code to this and it did the trick . A big thanks to everyone for helping .

Pretty obvious solution , somehow i missed it .